# How to print the comand line of some linux process

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to print the command line of the python process currently running on my machine, I tried things like this:

```
ps -A|grep python|awk "{cat /proc/$1/cmdline}"
```

but I seem unable to understand how awk works... I wanted a single line to make an alias, but you can suggest a better way

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `ps -o args= "$(pgrep python)"`

Comment: if you really want to `cat /proc/.../cmdline`: `pgrep python | xargs -r -I PID cat /proc/PID/cmdline`

Comment: @Aaron if there are more than one pids returned by `pgrep`, this would raise `error: process ID list syntax error`

Comment: I get `ps: unknown option -- A`, please post output of `uname -srv`. Good luck.

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks that works but shows all in one single line, it's difficult to read.

Comment: @sordnay; yeah, that's the (unintended) consequence of just doing `cat /proc/PID/cmdline` (as in your sample command) and hence my comment ... *if you really want to cat ...* :-)

Comment: oh, didnt know pgrep, nice! this gives more output I wanted... `pgrep -af python` that works for me. thanks guys!

Comment: not sure about @shellter and @thanasisp where referring to, but here is my complete uname: `Linux cocoon-l 4.15.0-122-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Note that generally, "how do I use UNIX tools?" questions are a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

```
pgrep -af python
```

thaks to @Aaron and @markp-fuso for the help!